# UPDATE php при условии

Tags: php, mysql, update

Есть 2 таблицы, мне необходимо при записи данных в ячейку одной, копировать их автоматом во вторую таблицу.

Ошибка вида:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in Z:\home\example.ru\www\includes\feedback.php on line

Сейчас код выглядит след. образом:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE `moderate`=1 ORDER BY `index`");
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($myrow['type'] == 0)
    {
        $result1 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `table_1` SET `image`= (SELECT `image` FROM table_2 WHERE user_id=".$myrow['user_id']);
        while ($myrow1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
        {
            ?>
            <div class="feedback-mainpage">
                <div class="feedback-mainpage-photo">
                        <div class="circle-photo" style="background: url(<?php if ($myrow1['image0']=='') echo '/images/photobydefault.jpg'; else echo '/images/pages_img/'.$myrow1['image0']; ?>)"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="feedback-mainpage-text">
                    <p><?= $myrow['text'] ?></p>
                    <div class="author-contacts"><?= $myrow['title'] ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: При выполнении `UPDATE` запрос вам не вернет массив обновленных строк. Делайте `SELECT` после него.

Comment: это не решение Вашей проблемы, но исправьте код, пожалуйста. Скобку закрыть надо. Должно быть `$result1 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE table_1 SET image= (SELECT image FROM table_2 WHERE user_id=" . $myrow['user_id'] . ")");` А также кажется странным отсутствие `WHERE` внутри `UPDATE`. Вы таким образом запишете одно и тоже во все записи таблицы

Comment: @cyadvert не могли бы пожалуйста насчёт where в update объяснить) немного не понимаю к чему его привязать... Если честно. А что касается в данном случае корректности запроса? Visman написал, что update не вернёт массив обновлённых строк, о чем видимо и говорит ошибка...

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что одни и те же данные нужно одновременно засунуть сразу в две таблицы? Тогда можно это сделать одним запросом примерно так: `UPDATE tab_1, tab_2 SET tab_1.field=1, tab_2.field=1 WHERE tab_1.field_id=$id AND tab_2.field_id=$id`

Comment: @Artyom Sosonko, `WHERE` задаёт условие для вашего запроса. Если например вы хотите обновить(или получить) какие-то данные у пользователя `petya` в колонке `names`, то условие будет выглядеть так: `WHERE names='petya'`.

Comment: @stashappy В одну таблицу (table_2) они попадают автоматически при выполнении пользователем определенных действий. А мне нужно при обновлении первой таблицы копировать определенные данные во вторую таблицу...

Comment: @Artyom Sosonko, в таком случае, сразу **после обновления** данных в `table_1`, нужно делать выборку из `table_1` и заносить данные в `table_2`. По другому кажется и не получится. У Вас в запросе, нужно выставить `WHERE`, иначе будут обновляться все записи в таблице. Если же вы хотите обновить конкретную запись, то вам нужно знать её `id` и выставлять условие согласно следующей формулировке: `WHERE` `имя столбца`=$id. В таком случае будет обновлена только одна запись. Делать выборку из БД, нужно аналогичным образом, используя эту же формулировку.

Comment: @stashappy Понял, спасибо большое, единственное, у меня ведь сейчас фактически и структура кода неправильная, раз php ругается. То бишь действительно мне надо разбивать запрос на 2? UPDATE отдельно, SELECT отдельно? Или все же можно как-то побороть такую конструкцию?) Помимо всего прочего явно имеются синтаксические ошибки, cyadvert я так понимаю корректно их исправил)

Comment: @Artyom Sosonko, После обновления записи в таблице `table_1`, данные сразу должны обновляются и в таблице `table_2`. Затем обновлённые данные выводятся на страницу из таблицы `table_2`. Правильно я описал порядок действий? Мне нужно понять, что и откуда должно идти и тогда я смогу Вам помочь.

Comment: @stashappy порядок верный, только таблицы местами поменять)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE moderate=1 ORDER BY index", $db);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['type'] == 0) {
        $get_image = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT image FROM table_2 WHERE user_id=".$row['user_id'], $db));
        mysqli_query("UPDATE table_1 SET image=".$get_image['image']." WHERE user_id=".$row['user_id']." LIMIT 1", $db);
            ?>
            <div class="feedback-mainpage">
                <div class="feedback-mainpage-photo">
                        <div class="circle-photo" style="background:url(
                        <?php
                            if($get_image['image']=="") {
                                echo '/images/photobydefault.jpg';
                            } else {
                                echo '/images/pages_img/'.$get_image['image'];
                            }
                        ?>
                        );"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="feedback-mainpage-text">
                    <p><?php echo $row['text'] ?></p>
                    <div class="author-contacts"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Так оно и не работает в итоге?

Comment: пока что не было возможности проверить) сегодня-завтра) спасибо!